# Set functions for blank keys after switching from Japanese to English Keyboard Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have a Japanese keyboard laptop, I have mapped it to English format because of which I have a few extra keys. Can I do something to map them for existing functions? Like there is a key to the left of backspace which does nothing and I would like to map it for backspace.

Comment: What exactly does "have mapped it to English format" mean?

Comment: Just change the Input source of Keyboard. 
Settings -> Region and Language -> Keyboard Layout, and then select source as "English US"

Answer (score 0):

Keymappings are kept at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`. I have a laptop on which I swap around home/end and pgup/pgdown because their positions on the keyboard irk me. If you can figure out where those keys are assigned in those configs, it should just be a matter of assigning them with the right code to match the key you want them to press. Remember to log out and in after each reassignment.

If you REALLY want to get involved with it, [Here's](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/xorg-docs/input/XKB-Enhancing.html) the xorg xkb page detailing how to really work with it, but for simple reassignment you shouldn't need to go that in-depth.

Comment: Okay. So I saw the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/jp`  and found the code 
`partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "OADG109A" {

    include "jp(common)"
    name[Group1]= "Japanese (OADG 109A)";

    key <AE10> { [ 0            ] };
    key <AE13> { [ yen, bar     ] };
};
`
from this, AE13 seems to be our key code.
Correspondingly, I added the line `key <AE13> { [ BackSpace, BackSpace     ] };` in file `/symbols/us`, logged out and logged in again, but still it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I tried modifying other key mappingsin `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` and that is applying the changes, but somehow the BackSpace addition change doesn't work

Comment: that is adding the line `key <AE13> { [ equal, plus  ] } ;` maps the key to equal and plus as expected but  `key <AE13> { [ BackSpace, BackSpace  ] } ;` doesn't map it to backSpace